# Limit scan angle of RPLidar A1

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, mapping, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have RPLidar A1 device and I would like to know how I could limit the scan angle from 0 degrees to 180 degrees using Hector Mapping Slam.

Note: I am using ROS indigo on ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271124/limit-scan-angle-of-rplidar-a1/) by [Hamad](https://answers.ros.org/users/31944/hamad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By using [LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_filters#LaserScanAngularBoundsFilter)

---

Originally posted by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) with karma: 161 on 2017-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamad](https://answers.ros.org/users/31944/hamad/) on 2017-09-27**:
I have tried that but did not work for me; it might be there is something that I am doing wrong. If you have any experience with this, please give the instruction how to run it.

**Comment by [naveedhd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26074/naveedhd/) on 2017-09-28**:
Try following the example launch and use yaml file given in the tutorial, by replacing with your desired angles. If you need explanation of any part, feel free to ask.

**Comment by [Hamad](https://answers.ros.org/users/31944/hamad/) on 2017-10-09**:
the problem is when you run the ros indigo using the PRlidar view_slam I do not know how to run it with leaser filter in order to limit my angles if you know how to do this give me more explanation on it